# How to mention once to ignore 2 folders with same name from different directories using gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have following folders in my project.

```
public/first/A
public/second/A
public/first/B
public/second/B
```

And similarly I've other folders which is also in `public/first` and `public/second`.

To ignore these folders I need to add following to .gitignore :

```
/public/first/A
/public/second/A
....
```

Is there a way which I can follow to mention `A` and `B` folder only once in gitignore and they will be ignored from both `/public/first` and `/public/second`.

> Note:  Folders with **A** & **B** name with different content might be available in other folders like `public/first/app/A` and it should not be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that there is no `/public/third/A` scenario, you can use a wildcard to specify the `first` and `second` part. Like this

```
/public/*/A/
/public/*/B/
```

Also, you need to put a `/` after a folder in gitignore. If you don't, git treats it like a file declaration instead of a folder.

Comment: How to handle it if I've a scenario `/public/third/A/` ? One of the possibility I know is adding `!/public/third/A/` to gitignore. Though I need to follow this to add all folders which **should not be** ignored.

Comment: Yeah, you'd have  to do that. Though if your `third` folder has nothing else that needs to go into gitignore, you can simply do `!/public/third/`